# Remove Duplicate XML Section with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have been working on a script to parse an xml document in order to find any duplicates of a specific section inside the file. For context, this is a part of a pre-process that the XML document goes through before it's passed through an import process.

I was able to narrow down the specific section that causes the import process to fail:

```
        <OrderLineAct IsEmpty="N" Imported="Y" RecordID="" Error="" Version="15.4.0.3" OrderNumber="21-000138765">
            <Code>RR</Code>
            <CodeType>POSITION</CodeType>
            <JobCodeID>0</JobCodeID>
            <JobsFltID>0</JobsFltID>
            <LineID>16348542</LineID>
            <Modified>6/6/2018 8:50:00 AM</Modified>
            <ModifiedBy>JANETC</ModifiedBy>
            <OrderID>2294006</OrderID>
            <Qty>0</Qty>
            <QtyUOM></QtyUOM>
            <Section>3863523</Section>
        </OrderLineAct>
        <OrderLineAct IsEmpty="N" Imported="N" RecordID="" Error="" Version="15.4.0.3">
            <Code>RR</Code>
            <CodeType>POSITION</CodeType>
            <JobCodeID>0</JobCodeID>
            <JobsFltID>0</JobsFltID>
            <LineID>16348542</LineID>
            <Modified>6/6/2018 8:50:00 AM</Modified>
            <ModifiedBy>JANETC</ModifiedBy>
            <OrderID>2294006</OrderID>
            <Qty>0</Qty>
            <QtyUOM></QtyUOM>
            <Section>3863523</Section>
        </OrderLineAct>
```

Having this duplicate section causes the file to go through an infinite loop inside the importer, resulting in the file not completing it's import process.

What I need to do is determine if any one of these `OrderLineActs` is identical to an existing one inside its parent Node. Each one of these `OrderLineActs` resides inside of a `OrderLine` segment.

I'm having difficulty thinking about how to accomplish this. My first thought was to go through and delete anything that contains `Imported="N"`, but then could run into issues if another `OrderLineAct` fails the import for some reason.

My idea was to structure it similarly to how I am completely removing another tag inside the XML:

```
Function Remove-UnitMeter
{
    param($xml)

    # strip the xml of any UnitMeter tags - done for every schema
    foreach($VendorInvoice in $xml.VendorInvoices)
    {
        foreach($Order in $VendorInvoice.Order)
        {
            # remove the UnitMeter tag from the XML file
            if ($Order.UnitMeter -ne $null){
                $Order.RemoveChild($Order.UnitMeter) | Out-Null # out-null otherwise it'll output all of the tags
            }
        } # end order
    } # end vendorinvoice

    return $xml
}
```

I know I have to remove the child from the parent, but I need to be able to determine if it's a true duplicate before I do.

Has anyone ever done anything like this before? I can provide more information as needed. Thanks.

Comment: If you define **exactly** what you mean by "_true duplicate_", someone is more likely to help. E.g., all child nodes of the `OrderLineAct` node equal....or something simpler like else like identical `Version` attributes.

Comment: The nodes in your example are not identical. The top one has an extra attribute called `OrderNumber`. Apart from that, their content is the same. So maybe it is just a question of removing the OrderLineAct node that has no such attribute. Something like this perhaps?
`if (!$Order.OrderLineAct.OrderNumber) { # remove the node }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess all I have to do is walk away for a while because I figured it out.

```
#[xml]$xml = Get-Content "\\papertransport.com\files\UserDocuments\mneis\Code\XML\TMT XML Files\PTIInvoices_Exporting.18-06-11 03.31.13.xml"
[xml]$xml = Get-Content "\\pedi01\masgre\FTPTransfer.Received\EXCP_20180329042048.xml"

foreach($VendorInvoice in $xml.VendorInvoices)
{
    foreach($Order in $VendorInvoice.Order)
    {
        foreach($OrderSec in $Order.OrderSec)
        {
            foreach($OrderLine in $OrderSec.OrderLine)
            {
                # store the acts inside a node object (from the orderline object) because you need to get all of them
                # but only select the Code and CodeType
                if ($OrderLine.OrderLineAct -ne $null){
                    $OrderLineActs = $OrderLine.OrderLineAct | Select -Property Code, CodeType

                    # find the duplicate
                    foreach($OrderLineAct in $OrderLineActs)
                    {
                        if ($OrderLine.OrderLineAct -ne $null)
                        {
                            # select the uniques
                            $Unique = $OrderLineActs | Select * -Unique

                            # compare the two objects to find the duplicate - the duplicate will have a SideIndicator of <=
                            $ComparedObjects = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $OrderLineActs `
                                                              -DifferenceObject $Unique `
                                                              -IncludeEqual
                            $Duplicate = $ComparedObjects | Where {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}
                        }
                    } 

                    if ($Duplicate -ne $null){
                        $DuplicateAct = $OrderLine.OrderLineAct | Where {($_.Code -eq $Duplicate.InputObject.Code) -and ($_.CodeType -eq $Duplicate.InputObject.CodeType)}
                        $DuplicateAct = $DuplicateAct | Select -Last 1
                        Write-Host '-------------------Deleted-------------------'
                        $OrderLine.RemoveChild($DuplicateAct)
                    }
                }
            } # orderline
        } # ordersec
    } # order
} # vendor invoice

$xml.OuterXml | Out-file "C:\MyFiles\Temp\RemoveAct.xml"
```

Probably not the prettiest solution out there but it does what I need it to do. 
Basically what I do is create an object containing all of the things I want to compare, then filter down and narrow down the duplicates, then removing the section from the parent. If anyone else has a better solution please let me know!

Comment: The trick was to look at the first two values: `Code` and `CodeType` and drive the comparison off of those two values.